# How do I remove "nearby cocktail bars" on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, maps

A friend of mine in AA (Alcoholics Anonymous) asked me if I knew of a way to remove "nearby bars" from his iPhone. This appears when you swipe left and the built in Maps feature displays this.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you set some parental restrictions of that would be suppressed.

Comment: I just sent [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback) to Apple suggesting this should be removable.  Specifically mentioning those in recovery thru AA.  The more people that send feedback the faster it will be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can open settings -> general -> Spotlight Search, then turn off maps. This is a workaround, but it will not give you gas stations or anything of that type either.